# How to ask for someone to call when lunch is over

Tags: tense, indian-english

I want my friend to call me once he is finished his lunch. What is the most correct way?

> 1. Please tell me once eat lunch.
> 2. Please tell me once ate lunch.
> 3. Please tell me once have eaten lunch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please tell me once eat lunch or Please tell me once ate lunch or Please tell me once have eaten lunch

Well, none of them are correct. You wrote

> **I want** my friend to **call me** **once** he is **finished** his **lunch**.

One way to say this is

> **I want** *you to* **call me** *when you have* **finished** your **lunch**.

or

> Please call me when you finish your lunch.

We can also say

> Please call me "after you eat" or "after you are done eating lunch"

if we wanted to keep "eat" in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would prefer to say:
"Can you call me after having lunch, please?"
Or "Could you call me after you have finished your lunch, please?"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/127437)